# Building an API structure, members of a module are scoped to wrong namespace

Tags: .net, vb.net, dll, structure, hierarchy

I'm using **Visual Studio 2013**, trying to develop an own API that has this members structure:

[image]

The problem is that the members of the `Extensions` module are exposed in `Elektro.Xml.Extensions` but also in `Elektro.Xml` :

[image]  [image]

Why happens this? and how to fix it?.

---

### Extensions.vb

```
Public Module Extensions

#Region " Public Extension Methods "

#Region " Type Conversion "

    <Extension>
    Public Function ToXDocument(ByVal sender As XmlDocument) As XDocument
       ...
    End Function

#End Region

#End Region

End Module
```

### XmlUtil.vb

```
Public NotInheritable Class XmlUtil

#Region " Public Methods "

    Public Shared Function XmlBeautifier(...) As String
        ...
    End Function

#End Region

End Class
```

Comment: You don't fix it. It's normal. C# has exactly the same thing where extension methods are visible *either* by their namespace being in scope via a `using` directive (VB `Imports`) *or* by making direct reference to the `static` class that contains them.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Thanks for comment. Please fix me If I'm wrong, but I think you aren't referring to the problem I described, you mean that extensions are accesible from the module that owns the methods ( `Namespace.MyStringExtension(MyString, more params)` ) and also from an instance of the type that the extension methods accept in the first parameter ( `MyString.MyStringExtension(more params)` ), of course, I know that, but what I'm asking is that the members of the module are shown in two different namespaces!, in `Elektro.Xml` and also in `Elektro.Xml.Extensions`, is that normal?.

Comment: Yes, see [Type Promotion](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xz7s1h1x.aspx) (Although I think some of the code samples are messed up on that page): "When you declare a programming element in a module, Visual Basic promotes its scope to the namespace containing the module"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Examining a random 3rd party API in github (something that I normally do to discover new techniques and acquire knowledge) I found that to solve this issue the developer just could set the `HideModuleName` attribute to the module and *voilá*.

- **[HideModuleNameAttribute Class - MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/85a47y0y%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)**

Comment: I'm disappointed that you describe my answer as "wrong". I've described *standard* behaviour.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Excuse me, my English is not so good to express myself as I want, "wrong" was not the proper word, maybe "missing", "incomplete" or "outdated", because this attribute applies to the VB rules that you mentioned they can't do this, but they can. Thanks for comment

Comment: A word of caution. People often go to not insignificant lengths to help others. When an OP does a self-answer and tweaks some triviality or the like, it *can* make solution providers rather irritated and not want to help much for a while. I once helped a guy with 5k rep who then just did a self-answer because his *path* to the files were different than my example

Comment: @Drew Thanks for comment. Just I would like to say that I don't feel identified with your comment, the case you exposed of that guy... he was just stupid, but I think this is different, the actual answer has provided very useful info but didn't provided a solution, more than that, he said there is no solution (not with these words but), I gave him an upvote and accepted him solution, until now, because I found a SOLUTION.

Comment: fair enough, I was just saying, knowing all along it may have nothing to do with your situation. Keep on truckin'

Answer (score 2):

This is standard, and not something to be "fixed". For more detail, please see section 7.7 of the [Visual Basic Language Specification](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=15039):

> A member of a standard module has two fully qualified names, one without the standard module name and one with the standard module name. More than one standard module in a namespace may define a member with a particular name; unqualified references to the name outside of either module are ambiguous. For example:

```
Namespace N1
    Module M1
        Sub S1()
        End Sub

        Sub S2()
        End Sub
    End Module

    Module M2
        Sub S2()
        End Sub
    End Module

    Module M3
        Sub Main()
            S1()       ' Valid: Calls N1.M1.S1.
            N1.S1()    ' Valid: Calls N1.M1.S1.
            S2()       ' Not valid: ambiguous.
            N1.S2()    ' Not valid: ambiguous.
            N1.M2.S2() ' Valid: Calls N1.M2.S2.
        End Sub
    End Module
End Namespace
```

Comment: but then, what approach I have to prevent that annonying effect?, I don't see .Net framework class library namespaces full of annonying extension methods, I hope exists some workaround for this when building the data structures. I don't want to compile an additional dll/VS solution lets say "Elektro.XmlExtensions" just to store a little pack of extensions... the module should be part of the "Elektro.Xml" namespace. Thanks for answer.

Comment: @ElektroStudios - most, if not all, .Net framework class libraries are implemented in C#, not VB. C# has slightly different rules here (it uses `static` classes rather than "modules" and the rules there are somewhat different). So, there's an *obvious* way to not get this "annoying" behaviour, but it may not be one that you're able or willing to go with.

Comment: @ElektroStudios - and moving it to a separate DLL wouldn't "fix" it I believe - if you're VB consuming VB, then VB rules apply.